# What is the difference between declarative HTML helpers and HTML helpers in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

In many places you hear developers talk about **Declarative HTML helpers** or **HTML helpers**. What is their difference. Are they just synonyms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Declarative HTML helpers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) use the `@helper` function and are declared inline inside the Razor views.

HTML helpers are extension methods declared in separate classes and can be used in any view engine (Razor, WebForms, Spark, ...).